# The restriction of a Riemannian metric might be degenerate?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that $(M,g)$ is a Riemannain space and $P\subset M$ is a submanifold. If the restriction of $g$ on $T_pP$, for every $p\in P$, is non-degenerate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction of a positive define scalar product on a vector subspace is always non degenerated. Since $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ if and only if $u=0$ thus $\langle u,.\rangle$ is not zero.

The restriction of $g$ on $P$ is defined for $x\in P$ as the restriction of the scalar product $g_x$ of $T_xM$ to $T_xP$ so it is non degenerated.